# SQL Server 2008 R2 - Some database in an instance cannot be connected until SQL Server Management Studio is opened

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have several installations of same software (developed in VB) at various locations. An instance having three databases is created for this software at every location. But at a particular location, only one database can be connected. Other two databases give connection error. I cannot connect from even the server.

The surprising part is, when I open SQL Server Management Studio from same user, every database can be connected from SSMS as well from software. If SSMS is closed, again same problem continues.

It is obvious that users cannot be granted SSMS and database access. So a solution is compulsory. Could not find a solution anywhere. Please help.

Comment: what is the error message ?

Comment: Is auto close database property set?

Comment: Error is : SQL Server detected a logical consistency-based I/O error: incorrect checksum (expected: 0xc3f910b8; actual: 0xc3f911b8). It occurred during a read of page (1:9227) in database ID 7 at offset 0x00000004816000 in file 'D:\AIMSGST\Data\MSSQL10_50.RIS\MSSQL\DATA\LEER1718.mdf'.  Additional messages in the SQL Server error log or system event log may provide more detail. This is a severe error condition that threatens database integrity and must be corrected immediately. Complete a full database consistency check (DBCC CHECKDB). But after opening in SSMS, everything works fine.

Comment: auto close property is False. Also once the software connects to database, it remains active until the software is closed. To connect again from software, we have to start SSMS again and take backup or some other activity. Then it connects again

Comment: That sounds like a serious error in the database, and one that you ought to address with a consistency check.  Figuring out how to ignore the error (as SSMS seems to) is not the right solution!!

Answer (score 0):

This problem had occurred due to corrupted database only. Although consistency check did not report any error, after repairing database, it could be overcome.

Only surprising part is, with error also it opened in SQL Server Management Studio. And everything worked well.

Thanks for this suggestion in comments.